# Override registered interface behaviour with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have WebApi project that has reference on other my project DataAccess.

In DataAccess I have registered `IDbSessionManager` as

```
builder.RegisterType<DbSessionManager>().As<IDbSessionManager>();
```

In WebApi project I want to override this registration in next way:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbSessionManager>().As<IDbSessionManager>().InstancePerRequest();
```

If I add both registrations, then Autofac throws exception

> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.

It can be solved if I remove registration from WebApi project or change it in this way:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbSessionManager>().As<IDbSessionManager>().SingleInstance();
```

But I need that `IDbSessionManager` was resolved per request.

Previously there was one solution to update container but now `Update` method are deprecated.

Is there any other way of doing this? Maybe using extension method like `OnlyIf` ?

Comment: This error means that you are resolving something outside a http context request. Is it normal that something in your application try to resolve such a type without current http context? Could you describe your desired  *Autofac* behavior in such a case ?

Comment: Problem - I can't find that something...

Comment: You can have a look at the call stack. It usually contains lot of information to find this *something*. This link from the documentation will also helps you : http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#troubleshooting-per-request-dependencies

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612). Whether `DataAccess` is a layer of an application or a [framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/), it should not have any Autofac DI configuration within it. If you put all of your composition root in your *entry assembly*, there will be no need to override any existing configuration. Related: [composition root reuse](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/).